# Different ASCII value for one character

Tags: c#, ascii, windows-ce, zxing

I'm making a c# program which generates a QRCode with the ZXing library to be read by a Windows Mobile Handheld device (c# but proprietary barcode reader : Motorola Symbol)

I set the tag content to `é` (acute lowercase e) with a winform textbox and give it to read to my device, which reads `Ú` (acute uppercase U)

When I read the tag with the Android Barcode Scanner it reads `é`...

[I cannot upload images here, i'll post the barcode later]

I suppose encoding is the problem here so I took a look on the bytes sent : 233

On this website : http://www.ascii-code.com/ , it says that `é` is 233 which is the expected behavior. But on this website : http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ is says that `é` is 130 and `Ú` is 233 ! (btw I'm typing Alt+233 to display Ú on my Windows computer)

EDIT : apparently the first website shows ISO-8859-1 (windows-1252) characters. But the question remains : **in which encoding is `é` coded 130 as per the second website** ?

EDIT 2 : I completely agree that UTF-8 will easily solve my problem (works with android, but I can't tell my device "Hey this barcode is UTF-8 encoded!" so it will show me raw information, see answer below.

- What is happening ? (edit : answered, single symbol encoding mismatch)
- Is it normal to have two specific ASCII values for one character ? (edit : answered, two encodings are used)
- Since I receive a 233 code, how can I tell the Handheld device to convert this value ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: ASCII is only 7 bit; there's no such thing as an ASCII code of 130 or 233; by definition: *that isn't ASCII*. So then you need to ask: what is the codepage / encoding being used? We can't tell you.

Comment: Agreed for better naming convention. So how can I call those values which are greater than 127 ? The first website says it's ISO-8859-1 (so Windows-1252 I suppose) but what about the second website ?

Comment: Okay. These sites talk about "extended ascii" but are completely meaningless without the encoding context, thus the incomprehension, thus this stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I get it : the barcode reader of the device reads data in **DOS 850** encoding !

The first hint was the keyboard : by looking on the web I found that you can see your default encoding in Windows by typing the command `chcp`. It shows 850 on my computer. A quick googling sent me to this page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850 **where `é` is 130 ! Yay !**

All I had to do is tell the device to display the values as Windows-1252 charset :

```
Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetBytes(txt),0,txt.Length);
```

For the general purpose of the question, thanks to @MarkGravell, the websites where falsely talking about general "extended ascii" codes, but these codes change between encodings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:DOS_code_pages) and are therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal to have 2 different characters for the same ASCII code. Read about ASCII code pages like Win1250,1251,1252...

Comment: I disagree with the language used here; no, it is not normal to have 2 characters for the same ASCII code. It is, however, true that the same **raw bytes**, when interpreted by different encodings / code-pages, can yield different *code-points*. Code-pages that aren't ASCII (such as the one's you've listed): **aren't ASCII**. Now, we could argue semantics of whether 8-bit extended ASCII code-pages are truly ASCII, but : it is meaningless to talk about them unless you also explicitly mention *which code-page*

Comment: simple; everything I said previously starting "Now, we could..." - this is Windows Codepage 1250. It should **not** be called simply "ASCII", and it *isn't* simply "ASCII". Back in the day, it might have been called "ANSI"

Comment: OK, we are talking about code pages. The word ASCII is not fully correct in the question and I used the same terminology in my answer. When 1 million people use one word incorrectly, it changes its meaning. ANSI was used in the old Windows days... nearly to Windows 98. Now young developers don't know what is it (in code page context).

Comment: let's limit ourself to programmers; estimates for the number of programmers vary between 10M and 20M; so that's 5-10% of them that are using a technical term incorrectly; I don't think that is enough to change what the technical term means.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok. Explain this to Goufalite. He is asking about _ASCII_ code 233, etc. and canonical ASCII are up to 127.

Comment: I have tried to do so; let's move one more person from the 5-10% to the 90-95% bucket

Answer (score 0):

ASCII code is unique on 7 bits (between 0 and 127) . However, there are a lot of different extended versions on 8 bits. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII
If you need special characters as "é" or "ù", I would suggest you to use a UTF-(8 or 16) encoding or Unicode.

Comment: Agreed on UTF-8, but : `é` is `Ã©`. The Handheld device will interpret those as `├®` (android has no problem!) which is worse. I've edited my question : I cannot tell my device "hey this barcode is UTF-8 encoded"